# Sending empty content with HttpRequestMessage

Tags: asp.net-web-api

When dealing with the HttpRequestMessage, does the Content field always have to be non-null?  If yes, then what If I want to send an empty body?  How would one specify that?

For example, with a DELETE or GET request.

Comment: How come? What do you want to do that you cannot? Of course you can send empty content. Bring an example please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely should allow an empty content. As you quite rightly point out, DELETE and GET never have content bodies, and there's no strict requirement to have one for POST either.

I usually use HttpClient, and just use an empty StringContent, e.g.

```
var response = _connection.Client.PostAsync(path, new StringContent(string.Empty)).Result;
```